# Retrofit Multipart Image Upload issue retrofit.RetrofitError java.io.InterruptedIOException

Tags: android, image-uploading, retrofit, okhttp

I am trying to upload image through multipart in retrofit. I am frequently getting the following exception.

```
Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError: timeout
   at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:395)
   at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
   at $Proxy1.uploadImage(Native Method)
   at gaadi.evaluator.com.retrofit.RetrofitRequest.makeImageUploadRequest(RetrofitRequest.java:24)
   at gaadi.evaluator.com.service.RetrofitCarImageUploadService.onHandleIntent(RetrofitCarImageUploadService.java:59)
   ... 4 more



Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout
   at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:258)
   at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:158)
   at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
   at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:46)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSink.write(HttpConnection.java:302)
   at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
   at okio.RealBufferedSink$1.write(RealBufferedSink.java:198)
   at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
   at retrofit.mime.TypedByteArray.writeTo(TypedByteArray.java:66)
   at retrofit.client.OkClient$1.writeTo(OkClient.java:88)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:898)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:760)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:274)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:230)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:201)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:81)
   at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
   at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
   ... 8 more



Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
   at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
   at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:151)
   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
   at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:517)
   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:511)
   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
   at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:78)
   at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
```

Version of retrofit library used : retrofit:1.9.0
Version of okhttp used :okhttp:2.4.0

The REST retrofit adapter i am using is as following :

```
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okHttpClient.setWriteTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(urlBase)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.BASIC)
                .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
                .build();
```

Interface method used for making request is as follows :

```
@Multipart
@POST("/{path}")
public ImageUploadResponse uploadImage(@Path("path") String path,       @Part(Constants.EVALUATION_DATA) String map, @Part("certImg") TypedFile file);
```

Call made to this interface method is as follows :

```
TypedFile file = new TypedFile("multipart/form-data", new File(imagePath));
String url = Utils.getWebServiceURL(UILApplication.getInstance());
return requestInterface.uploadDocumentImage(path, jsonParams, file);
```

Also I tried setting timeout values from 30 to 60 . It did not help !!

Any help would be appreciated !!!

PS: This code works fine on wifi connection but fails on 3G mobile data network.

Comment: What if you make 30 sec to 60sec?  Is your request content is too large?

Comment: @kaitian I tried that too . But it did not work !!

Comment: would you like to give your detailed url and query so I can test it on my machine

Comment: @kaitian i have added the interface method i am using to make this happen. I cannot post the exact server url here .

Answer (score 0):

This is due to server side issue. Server is resetting the connection before 
data/image being uploaded .

As suggested by Jake Wharton :
https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1027